# Exact number of groups of order $1536$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, groups-enumeration

Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $1536 = 2^9 \cdot 3$.

**Question:**

> How many groups of orders $1536$ are there?

**Attempt:**

Let $P_2$ and $P_3$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroups and **the** Sylow $3$-subgroup (there is only one Sylow $3$-subgroup. See Edit 2), respectively. This means that $|P_2| = 2^9$ and $|P_3| = 3$. One can show that $G = P_3 \rtimes P_2$, where $\rtimes$ is the inner semidirect product. Also, if $n_2 = 1$ (i.e., there is only one Sylow $2$-subgroups), then $G \cong P_2 \times P_3$, that is, the direct product of $P_2$ and $P_3$. From this [Wikipedia post](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_given_order#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of%20groups%20of%20order%20is%20defined,on%20the%20nature%20of%20the%20prime%20factorization%20of.) the maximum number of groups of order $1536$ is bounded above by $1536^{{1536}^{2}}$. However, the same post says that there are exactly $10,494,213$ groups of order $512 = 2^9$ and $1$ group of order $3$ (namely, $\mathbb{Z}_3$). In general, if $N_m$ is the number of groups of order $m = ab < \infty$ with coprime numbers $a$ and $b$, then $N_a \cdot N_b \le N_m \le m^{{m}^{2}}$. Hence, $10,494,213 \le N_{1536} \le 1536^{{1536}^{2}}$.

**Restating the question:**

> What is the exact number for $N_{1536}$, given that $$10,494,213 \le N_{1536} \le 1536^{{1536}^{2}}?$$

### EDIT

This question is this paper of [Exercises - Group Theory (Exercise 3, pg. 1)](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/exercises_groups.pdf)

### Edit 2

Proof of why $P_3$ (Sylow $3$-subgroup) is the unique normal subgroup of $G$ of order $1536$.

**Proof:**
Recall the following two Sylow Theorems:

> **Second Sylow Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group of order $p^k m$, where $p$ is prime and $p \nmid m$. If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $H$ is another Sylow $p$-subgroup, then they are conjugates. That is, $\exists x \in G$ such that $P = xHx^{-1}$.

> **Third Sylow Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group of order $p^k m$, with $\gcd(p,m)=1$, and $n_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$ subgroups of $G$. Then, $n_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $n_p | m$.

Let $n_p$ denote number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. Since $|G| = 1536 = 2^9 \cdot 3$, let $P_3$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup of order $3$. Now, let's calculate $n_3$. By the Third Sylow Theorem, $n_3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $n_3|2$. Hence, $n_3 \in \{1,4,7,10, \dots\} \cap \{1,2\} = \{1\}$. Therefore, $n_3 =1$.

Now, let's prove normality. By the Second Sylow Theorem, $\exists g \in G$ such that $P_3 = gP_3g^{-1}$. To see this, since $n_3 =1$, then for any other Sylow $3$-subgroup $H$, $$H = P_3$$
However, $H = gP_3g^{-1}$ because both are Sylow $3$ subgroups, and hence, conjugates. Therefore, $$P_3 = gP_3g^{-1}$$ for some $g \in G$.

Comment: Why is a Sylow $3$-subgroup necessarily normal, as you assert? I think that's wrong. Take $A_4$, of order $12=3\times 4$, whose $3$-Sylows are not normal (there are 4 of them). Now let $K$ be any group of order $2^7$, and let $G=A_4\times K$. The 3-Sylows are not normal, so this group is not a semidirect product $P_3\rtimes P_2$.

Comment: (And you should not talk about **the** (singular definite article) Sylow $p$-subgroup unless you've shown there is only one. You should say "Let $P_2$ and $P_3$ be **a** Sylow $2$-subgroup and Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$, respectively.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I wrote a proof in Edit 2. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, it may not work in general. **HOWEVER,** it will **ALWAYS** work if $n_p =1$, i.e., the number of Sylow p-subgroups is unique.

Comment: According to [groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_1536) there are $408641062$ groups of order $1536$. To determine the number of groups of some order you usually argue using semidirect products and finding homomorphisms however in this case this seems rather difficult.

Comment: You are misapplying the theorem Here, $m=2^9$, not $2$ as you claim. So $n_3$ could certainly be $4$ (I gave you an explicit example). Or in principle it could be $16$, $64$, or $256$, all numbers satisfying the divisibility and congruence conditions.

Comment: Use \pmod to get the parentheses, not (\bmod ).

Comment: I don't know what "it" refers to in your shouty comment (all caps is the internet equivalent of shouting; use italics or boldface for emphasis). It is true that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is normal if and only if $n_p=1$. This is a consequence of the Second Sylow Theorem (any two are conjugate). But here you have no warrant to assert $n_3=1$. It certainly need not be normal or unique, as the explicit examples I gave you show.

Comment: Also, in [this](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/all_groups.pdf) earlier version of the same exercise sheet the problem is stated differently, prompting the reader to use the web to find the number of groups of order $1536$.

Comment: (And you are misquoting the Third Sylow Theorem: you are missing the hypothesis that $\gcd(p,m)=1$. I've added it for you.)

Comment: Thanks everybody! I learned my lesson: always check before talking.  Nevertheless, I am very blessed helping me with this.

Comment: For the record, the number of groups of this order was computed by a long computer calculation, and it makes no sense to attempt it as an exercise. Even order 512 is a long way beyond hand calculation. I think 128 might have been done originally by  hand, but there were lots of mistakes that were later corrected by computer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a really difficult calculation that is best done on a computer.

The answer turns out to be $408641062$.

Your lower bound, $10494213$, happens to be the number of *nilpotent* groups of order $1536$. This is because the number of nilpotent groups of order $n=p_1^{a_1} \dots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$s are prime is equal to the product

$$\prod_{i=1}^k(\text{number of groups of order }p_i^{a_i} ).$$

This is because nilpotent groups arise as the product of their Sylow subgroups, and all this product is doing is enumerating all possible combinations of what the Sylow subgroups can be.